# Local Admin password change throughout the domain

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting

I have been trying this script to reset all the local admin passwords, the script runs perfectly fine if there is only one server in the server list, however, if there are multiple servers, it throws errors as -

server x      "The user name could not be found."
The following exception occurred while retrieving member "SetInfo": "The user n
ame could not be found."
At C:\Users\v7t7adm\desktop\localadmin.ps1:18 char:15
+  $user.SetInfo <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ExtendedTypeSystemExceptio
   n
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseGetMember

Here is the script for i created -

```
$computers = Get-Content servers.txt
"Name`tStatus" | Out-File -FilePath C:\users\v7t7adm\desktop\results.csv
$user = "KArthur"
$password = "Pol!sh90&8"
foreach($server in $computers)
{
try{
    $user = [adsi]"WinNT://$server/$user,user"
    $user.SetPassword($password)
    "$server`tSuccess"
    "$server`tSuccess" | Out-File -FilePath C:\users\v7t7adm\desktop\results.csv -Append
    }
    catch{
        "$server`t" + $_.Exception.Message.ToString().Split(":")[1].Replace("`n","")
        "$server`t" + $_.Exception.Message.ToString().Split(":")[1].Replace("`n","") | Out-File -FilePath C:\users\v7t7adm\desktop\results.csv -Append

    }

 $user.SetInfo()

}
```

Comment: It is an extraordinarily bad idea to hard-code a plain-text password in a script. (It's also not good to post it on the Internet for all to see.)

Answer (score 1):

`$user` is initially a string containing the username. In the loop you overwrite it  with the ADSI object. It then gets used again in the `"WinNT://$server/$user,user"` string, which fails.

Just use another name for the `$user` in the loop and you should be fine.

Edit: Change your script to

```
$computers = Get-Content servers.txt
"Name`tStatus" | Out-File -FilePath C:\users\v7t7adm\desktop\results.csv
$user = "KArthur"
$password = "Pol!sh90&8"

foreach($server in $computers)
{
    try{
        $adsiUser = [adsi]"WinNT://$server/$user,user"
        $adsiUser.SetPassword($password)
        "$server`tSuccess"
        "$server`tSuccess" | Out-File -FilePath C:\users\v7t7adm\desktop\results.csv -Append
    }
    catch{
            "$server`t" + $_.Exception.Message.ToString().Split(":")[1].Replace("`n","")
            "$server`t" + $_.Exception.Message.ToString().Split(":")[1].Replace("`n","") | Out-File -FilePath C:\users\v7t7adm\desktop\results.csv -Append
    }

    $adsiUser.SetInfo()
}
```

Comment: It did not work, i declared $user and $password inside the loop and it worked.